# Windshield washer fluid won't spray anymore

Tags: bmw, windshield-washer, 325i

I have 2003 BMW 325i. The windshield washer won't spray anymore. I checked the windshield washer tank no clogs, checked hoses, the only thing is I don't know how to check is pump if it has one. Can anyone give me an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The pump is a motor. Do you hear it engage? You may need a helper to operate while you listen close to the reservoir if it's too noisy where you're at.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pump ( mine is a 2000 328i, expect it is the same ), the pump is a press fit into the ( IIRC ) front/bottom of the washer fluid tank.  There can be two pumps, one for headlight washers, if so equipped, one for the windshield.

Answer (score 0):

often there is a connection on the pump/motor on the whasher fluid tank,if you disconnect this you can use a test light connected to the connector to see if power reaches the pump.

If power reaches the connector the fault is in the pump/motor,if power does not reach the connector you have an electrical fault.

To find the fault you need to find and identify the fuse,if the fuse is intact you need to take a look at the wiring and connectors to see where the bad connection is.

you will need a wiring diagram to find and follow the wires,a car mechanic can help you get the diagram but you will have to pay for it.

If the fuse is blown you disconnect the connector from the pump/motor,replace the fuse and use a test light to see if power reaches the connector,if the fuse blows  again you have a short in the wiring and will need to take a look at the wiring diagram to find the fault.

If the fuse stays intact and you have power to the connector you can connect it to the pump/motor if the fuse blows the pump/motor needs to be replaced.